# Conditions in loop to ensure python only scrapes single div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While attempting to scrape this website: https://dining.umich.edu/menus-locations/dining-halls/mosher-jordan/ I have located the food item names by doing the following:

```css
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dining.umich.edu/menus-locations/dining-halls/mosher-jordan/"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

foodLocation = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-name')

for singleFood in foodLocation:
    food = singleFood.text
    print(food)
```

The problem is, I only want to print the food inside of the "World Palate Maize" section seen in the Lunch portion of the link. In the HTML, there are multiple divs that all contain the foods within a certain type (World Palate Maize, Hot Cereal, MBakery etc.) I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell the loop to only print inside of a certain section (certain div?). This may require an if statement or condition in the for loop but I am unsure about how to format/what to use as a condition to ensure this loop only prints the content from one section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like "Lunch" would always be the second div, so you can probably do

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'
}

url = "https://dining.umich.edu/menus-locations/dining-halls/mosher-jordan/"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

[breakfast, lunch, dinner] = soup.select('div#mdining-items div.courses')
foods = lunch.select('div.item-name')

for food in foods:
    print(food.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

One strategy could be to select more specific by text e.g. with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("Lunch")+div h4:-soup-contains("World Palate Maize") + ul .item-name')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dining.umich.edu/menus-locations/dining-halls/mosher-jordan/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

foodLocation = soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("Lunch")+div h4:-soup-contains("World Palate Maize") + ul .item-name')

for singleFood in foodLocation:
    food = singleFood.text
    print(food)
```

##### Output

```
Mojo Grilled Chicken
Italian White Bean Salad
```